# На сервере WPengine не могу настроить скачивание файлов Nginx на сайте с CMS Wordpress. Ошибка 404

Tags: wordpress, nginx, php-nginx

Кто-то знает правило, чтобы на сервере Nginx не было ошибки 404 при скачивании файла ?
Хостинг - WPengine.  Получается файлы скачиваются при нажатии на кнопку загрузить, где должно идти скачивание, а у меня выбивает enternal server error 404 ...

Comment: какой root установлен?  Покажите конфиг (команда nginx -T) Какой запрос?

Comment: А как это сделать ? Куда вписать эту команду через админку ?

Comment: Через админку никуда. Вы спросили про Nginx, Вам про него и ответили, данная команда выполняется непосредственно на сервере, например подключившись туда по ssh. Почему Вы уверены что проблема именно с Nginx, а не с чем-то другим?

Comment: Для начала определись какая ошибка. 404-это "not found" - файл отсутствует (возможно нет прав). Лечится корректной ссылкой и установкой прав. А enternal server error - это 500. Проблема на сервере. При ней изучаются логи. Только причём тут ВП?

Comment: Кстати, если не ошибаюсь то указанный хостиг должен решать все проблемы.